# Is this a valid way to test for equality among 3 values?

Tags: java

```
public static double tripleBet(Dice dice, double betAmount) {
    double payout = 0.0;
    double three_rolled = 3;

    if (dice.getFirst() == dice.getSecond() && dice.getThird() == dice.getFirst()) {
        payout = betAmount * three_rolled;
    } else {
        payout = -betAmount;
    }
    return payout;

}
```

Here I am comparing die in a game called "Chuck-a-luck." I need to simply return a payout amount if the player has bet the dice will all be the same.

The expression in the conditional statement is my main concern. I'd like to know if it is valid or "good practice" to write like this.

Any other advice is welcomed as well.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an important note: You are using floating point for currency values.  This is _guaranteed_ to give you unexpected results at some point.  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and 
[Is Floating Point Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/18157)

Comment: What's the type returned by `getFirst()` etc.? If anything other than a primitive, you should use `equals()` instead of `==`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen integers.

Comment: The if condition is fine. There is no really nice way to express it.

Comment: You're fine then. Changing the order might make it a bit more readable (`1 == 2 && 2 == 3` instead of `1 == 2 && 3 == 1`), but that's about all you can do.

Comment: @JimGarrison non-base 10 numbering systems can cause some problems it looks like.

Comment: For money, yes, because money is accounted for in base 10.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid. The `==` operator is transitive, meaning that A == B and B == C implies that A == C.

I would therefore probably write it as

```
if (dice.getFirst() == dice.getSecond() && dice.getSecond() == dice.getThird())
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine. It is also possible to write your own helper method for this.

```
@SafeVarargs
public static final boolean equals(Object... objs) {
    if (objs== null || objs.length < 2) return false; // You may return true or throw exception

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
        if (!Objects.equals(objs[i], objs[i + 1])) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This will make it easier for you to read later on, provided you may have to a use-case where you compare even more values.

```
 if (Helper.equals(dice.getFirst(), dice.getSecond(), dice.getThird()) {}
```

Comment: The `if` condition in your loop should be negated. Also, for 0 and 1 arguments, it would be more typical to return `true`. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth for formal reasons.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I don't see any problems with the code you have given.

Here are some *cosmetic* updates you can make to your code. Will make it look much simpler and reduce the number of lines and save you some **memory** as well in the process.

```
public static double tripleBet(Dice dice, double betAmount) {

    double three_rolled = 3;

    // Using Ternary Operator we eliminated the need for a separate variable "payout" by simple returning the resultant values to the caller method.

    return (dice.getFirst() == dice.getSecond() && dice.getThird() == dice.getFirst()) ? betAmount * three_rolled : -betAmount;
}
```

> P.S : If the value of the variable `three_rolled` will always stay as 3 then i think you can either assign it to a `byte` or a similar data type. Don't need a `double` for a value this small. Better **memory management** leads to a happy compiler and cleaner codes.

Comment: Why use a variable at all? Something wrong with `3`?

Comment: Yeah 3 is fine, but using direct values is not recommended, Plus **just in case** `three_rolled` needs to be changed in the future then, it would be impossible to do so if we simply replace a variable with a fixed value. This is why i mentioned **IF** in my *PS*

Comment: I’ll be testing everything today and have been thinking a lot about tips I’ve seen.

Comment: 'Using direct values is not recommended' *by whom*? Why? If you mean it should be a manifest constant, I would agree, but the code you posted doesn't exhibit that. It should be `public`, `static` and `final` to qualify as a manifest constant. Not a mutable local variable.